# How to verify Pacts against multiple versions of PACTS published

Tags: pact, pact-broker

I have used pact-jvm-provider-maven/ plugin to publish different versions (1.0.0 and 2.0.0) of pacts to Pact-Broker. I'm using following configuration to verify the pacts against the hosted Provider....

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>au.com.dius</groupId>
                <artifactId>pact-jvm-provider-maven_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <serviceProviders>
                        <serviceProvider>
                            <name>Books</name>
                        <pactBrokerUrl>http://localhost:80/</pactBrokerUrl>
                        </serviceProvider>
                    </serviceProviders>
                    <configuration>
                        <pact.showStacktrace>true</pact.showStacktrace>
                    </configuration>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

It is verifying only the latest pact version i.e 2.0.0.

For backword compatibility, i wanted to verify all the versions of PACTS published to Broker against the Provider service.

Has anyone done this successfully?

Answer (score 2):

You can verify different versions of pacts by using the tagging feature of the pact broker. See https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/master/pact-jvm-provider-maven/README.md#verifying-pacts-from-an-pact-broker-that-match-particular-tags-version-335 on how to use this with the Maven plugin.

Basically, you assign tags to the different versions (like PROD for 1.0.0 and TEST for 2.0.0), and then you can verify your providers against both of those versions.

Comment: Thanks Ronald. Looks like i need to use tagging feature for different version so that while validating, use different tags which internally maps to specific version.